# What is Arduino Nano external power and USB power input hardware difference?

Tags: arduino

I am powering an [Arduino Nano](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano) rev 3.0 device with an external USB power adapter (1000 mA). When I connect it to power input, board acts weird, and the servo goes bananas. If I use the same adapter on a USB port, board acts fine. I would like to leave the USB port free and use an external power supply. Why wouldn't board work from same power supply and what could I do to stabilize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your external USB power supply is manufactured with more than enough to power a few servos (1000 mA). Try to use another power supply (rated to 5 V @ +300 mA).

If you don't have another power supply, make sure the output is around 5 V, and put a **big** capacitor (200 uF or more) between the 5 V and GND on your Arduino. I suspect that the power supply might just have a half-wave bridge rectifier, which might be insufficient to drive the servo motors.

Comment: Should the capacitor be of same voltage? Or will 35V 200uF fit well too?

Comment: The voltage on the cap is the maximum voltage it can hold, you can use anything which is higher then 5v. 35V 200uF will be just fine

Comment: Agreed on the possible issue. The external power adapter probably has a very bad/dirty signal and makes the board reset/brownout/servos act up. Looking at the voltage on a scope (under load) might confirm the issue. Can you try on another usb power supply/charger that might be of better quality?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can only draw 100mA from the USB until the connected device negotiates over the USB protocol to receive more.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-get-more-than-100ma-from-a-usb-port

Answer (score 0):

5V is a bit low, you'll need at least 6.2V (IIRC) when powering the Arduino through the VIN or the barrel connector, for it to be stable